# Android custom URI Scheme not launching app on some versions of Android, but works on others

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, intentfilter

We have an app managed by a third party that we are able to launch from one of our websites hosted on our own domain.This was working fine for a time, but sometime within the last few months it started not working on some versions of Android.
Instead of launching the app it will go to a 404 page in the browser.

Here's the relevant `intent-filter` in the AndroidManifest

```
<intent-filter>
    <data scheme="http"
            host="m.ourdomain.net"
            path="/OurApp"/>
    <action name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And the links on our website look like so:

```
string linkAddress = "http://m.ourdomain.net/OurApp?Location=" + locName + "&IP_Address=" + ip;
```

Called by:

```
Response.Redirect(linkAddress);
```

I was able to test this on a number of devices:
It works on Android versions 4.0.4 (Moto Bionic) and 4.1.2 (Moto RAZR).
It does **not** work on versions 2.3.5 (HTC EVO) and 4.1.1 (HTC DNA).
(Could it be something with HTC?)

I also tested this with both Dolphin and FireFox on the 4.1.1 device, and the propblem persisted.

I noticed on the devices it does work on, our app is being set as the "Default app". If I remove it from the "Default app" then click on our link, the little popup will come up asking if I want to open the link with the browser or with our app.
This does not happen on the devices it doesn't work on.

Does anybody have any idea as to why this might be happening, and how I can resolve it?

Comment: I am affected from this "bug" apparently on a Samsung GT-I9001 with Android 2.3.6 installed. This not completely Android-related nor completely vendor-related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could it be something with HTC?

For the HTC DNA, yes. Or, perhaps more accurately, it is something with Apple. HTC elected to hack in some workarounds to a particular Apple patent they were sued over. I have [two](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/23/linkify-problem-patent-behavior.html) blog [posts](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/24/linkify-problem-detection-mitigation.html) from last year describing what's going on.

It is conceivable that they "backported" the hack onto the EVO as well.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the info. And thanks apple for being selfish and dumb. If I read your post correctly, there's nothing I can do since I'm launching from a website, correct? Could we perhaps have the app developers register/create the "app association" when it is installed, that way the chooser does not need to appear?

Comment: And why are other manufacturers not affected by this? Did they win this patent dispute against apple (I'm not entirely sure how patent claims work)?

Comment: @G_M: "If I read your post correctly, there's nothing I can do since I'm launching from a website, correct?" -- AFAIK, you are correct. "Could we perhaps have the app developers register/create the "app association" when it is installed, that way the chooser does not need to appear?" -- IIRC, you cannot invent new app associations, and so unless your app is a full Web browser, this will not work. "And why are other manufacturers not affected by this?" -- haven't been sued yet, litigation still pending, licensed the patent, etc. I am not aware of anyone else doing an HTC-style workaround.